# Migrate ga3 to ga4: multi domain referral exclusion

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-4

When using google analytics v3 (universal analytics, analytics.js) to v4 (gtag.js, firebase-analytics) we are trying to figure out how to support what we did in multi-domain sites:

- Referral Exclusion (wwww.site.com -> sub.site.com)
- Segment based on users interested in product vs users looking to login ([www.site.com](http://www.site.com) -> app.site.com/login)

We did that previously using filters and views, however that doesn't exist in v4, and I cannot find any updated docs on Referral Exclusion using v4.

Notes:

- We have Enhanced Metrics activated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use "event modifications" (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10085872) instead that check the event property page_referrer and unset it if it should be excluded?

Comment: intiresting! Though since that is client side, I dont beleive we can acheive what we want: which is retroactively excluding a session if that session at one point goes from one domain to the other (IE: click the "login" prompt at the top of the marketing page)